# Hibernate with Spring: too many connections

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

Our project is using Hibernate 3.2.7.ga and Springs is 2.5.6 to handle db interaction. 
On the production server, after a certain number of users connect (no more than 10) we start getting the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: 
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: 
Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

Which originates from:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: 
connection limit exceeded for non-superusers
```

Reading similar questions i found out that the culprit is usually in not using a pooling datasource. So i went to check the spring configuration and found this -

### applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

    <!-- ========================= RESOURCE DEFINITIONS ========================= -->

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location"><value>/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" > <!--class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">-->
        <property name="driverClassName"><value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value></property>
        <property name="url"><value>${jdbc.url}</value></property>
        <property name="username"><value>${jdbc.username}</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.password}</value></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            ....
        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory"><ref local="sessionFactory"/></property>
    </bean>


    <!-- ========================= BUSINESS OBJECT DEFINITIONS ========================= -->



    <bean id="HibernateSpringDaoTarget" class="cnr.dao.SpringHibernateDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory"><ref local="sessionFactory"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="SpringHibernateDao" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager"><ref local="transactionManager"/></property>
        <property name="target"><ref local="HibernateSpringDaoTarget"/></property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
                <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
                <prop key="load*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
                <prop key="store*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**SpringHibernateDAOImpl** extends **HibernateDaoSupport** and contains all our hibernate queries and updates. In code it is used by calling

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(httpRequest.getSession().getServletContext()).getBean("SpringHibernateDao");
```

The spring configuration would indicate the used data source is the Basic Data Source from Commons, which should support connection pooling.

Any ideas on what i should check?

[Update for comments]
As for the max active connections i changed the configuration file to

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" > <!--class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">-->
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>${jdbc.url}</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>${jdbc.username}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.password}</value></property>
    <property name="maxActive"><value>1</value></property>
</bean>
```

This did not fix the problem however.

Hibernate is 3.2.7.ga and Springs is 2.5.6

Some typical db code would be:

```
public void save(LikeRecord like){
    getHibernateTemplate().save(like);
}

public boolean existsUserWithEmail(String email){
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Utente.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email));
    Utente user = (Utente) crit.uniqueResult();
    if(user==null)return false;
    else return true;
}
public boolean existsUserWithUsername(String userName){
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Utente.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("loginid", userName));
    Utente user = (Utente) crit.uniqueResult();
    if(user==null)return false;
    else return true;
}
```

As for the transactions and the pool manager i was under the impression this was handled under the hood by the spring beans defined in the applicationContext but i'm not really sure about this.

Comment: Supports, yes, however you're assuming the [default values](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) (8) are acceptable. You might try lowering the number to match the requirements of your database.

Comment: Which spring version and show us some database code.

Comment: How do you manage transactions?

Comment: Also, can you show your connection pool configuration?

Comment: Answered the comments in a question update